# How do I initialize UrhoSharp in my application background?

Tags: c#, urhosharp

I'm trying to use UrhoSharp in my Xamarin application to play sound, but SoundSource seems to need Urho to be initialized, and I can't initialize Urho without errors.

Here is the code I am trying to run

```
public void PlayTestUrho()
    {
        using (System.IO.Stream wav_stream = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(wav_file_name))
        using (System.IO.MemoryStream mem_stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            wav_stream.CopyTo(mem_stream);
            Node node = new Node();
            SoundSource src = node.CreateComponent<SoundSource>();
            BufferedSoundStream soundStream = new BufferedSoundStream();
            soundStream.AddData(mem_stream.ToArray());
            soundStream.SetFormat(44100, true, true);
            src.AutoRemoveMode = AutoRemoveMode.Node;
            src.Enabled = true;
            src.Panning = panning;
            src.Gain = gain;
            src.Frequency = frequency;
            src.Play(soundStream);
        }
    }
```

However, when I run that, I get the following error message

> Urho.Application is not started yet. All urho objects should be
>   initialized after app.Run() since they need an active Context.

I tried adding the line `Urho.Application.CreateInstance(typeof(Urho.SimpleApplication)).Run();` (the closest thing to Urho.app.Run() I could find) in my App.xaml.cs constructor, but that line gives me this error message

> Failed to initialise SDL subsystem: Application didn't initialize
>   properly, did you include SDL_main.h in the file containing your
>   main() function?. You can omit this exception by subscribing to
>   Urho.Application.UnhandledException event and set Handled property to
>   True.

The only help I can find is the [SoundSynthesis](https://github.com/xamarin/urho-samples/blob/master/FeatureSamples/Core/29_SoundSynthesis/SoundSynthesis.cs) sample, but it seems all the samples assume all boilerplate overhead has been taken care. (I am also probably loading the wav file wrong, but I can worry about that after I get Urho to even try playing it)

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: @StephanBisschop Sort of. I never figured out how to get Urho to work, but the Nuget package "Xam.Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer" does what I needed.